# Tabla de horario

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

estoy intentando hacer una tabla de horarios, usando un array para que cree las filas de cada hora, pero no consigo que muestre el elemento de la array en la columna de la hora.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, intenta copiar tu código en lugar de una imagen, es mucho más útil y simple para ayudarte.

Comment: ¿has intentado usar {hora}?

Comment: Ha funcionado, yo estaba probando {hora/}, pq estaba pensando en esto otro <hora/> y no había caído en el detalle. Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Si te ha servido marca la respuesta como correcta, no olvides evitar las imágenes de código y usar el editor de texto para mostrar tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta emplear {hora} para poder renderizar la variable

Comment: Ha funcionado, muchas gracias!!!!!